# How could I view tx pool on rinkeby via infura?

Tags: rinkeby, infura, txpool, ethernodes

I use rinkeby test network over infura provider from nodejs app.
Some of my transactions stuck in pending state. They are not shown in etherscan explorer pending list, but could be found by the hash. So I believe they stuck in a mining node local pool.
I want to get list of my pending tx to check if they are underpaid or something else.

How could I view rinkeby node local pool transaction list (like web3.txpool.inspect in geth), bearing in mind that I'm connecting from my app over Infura provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infura doesn't provide any methods to view pending transactions. According to [this](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/69) Github issue

> We don't support the parity specific methods. We also don't provide
>   the txpool geth methods either